# Population program in C++

Tags: c++

I'm in desperate need of assistance.
I'm working on a population program in C++ for my Systems Software class.

This is my first foray into C++ territory, I only have some Java knowledge to help me out.
Basically, the program is supposed simulate a simple population. The guidelines are as follows:

1. The first elements (starting population) have random age and sex.
2. 2 elements can pair if their lifespan falls between [0.25,0.50] (assuming they die at 1) and they are of the opposite sex.
3. Each element can only pair twice.

So here's my code, and take it easy guys I'm not very well versed in C++ yet...:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

class Element {
  public:
    int pair;
    double life;
    int tag;

  void setValues(double, int);

  int getPair() {
    return pair;
  }

  void incrementPair() {
    pair = pair++;
  }

  double getLife() {
    return life;
  }

  void incrementLife() {
    life = life + 0.05;
  }

  int getTag() {
    return tag;
  }
}; //Element

void Element::setValues(double b, int c) {
    pair = 0;
    life = b;
    tag = c;
}

int main() {
  double Time = 0.0;

  srand(time(NULL));
  vector<Element> vec;

  for (int i = 0; i<50; ++i) {
    Element x;
    x.setValues(((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)), rand()%2);
    vec.push_back(x);
  }//for

  while (vec.size() != 0) {
    int newPopCount = 0;
    int Dead = 0;

    for(int count = 0; count != vec.size(); ) {
      std::vector<Element>::iterator p = vec.begin();
      std::vector<Element>::iterator i = vec.begin() + 1;

      if ((p->getPair() == 2) || (p->getLife() < 0.25) || (p->getLife() > 0.50)) {
        count++;
        p++;
      }//if
      else {      

        for(int count1 = count + 1 ; count1 != vec.size() ; ) {
          if ((i->getLife() < 0.25) || (i->getLife() > 0.50) || (i->getPair() == 2) || (p->getTag() == i->getTag())) {
            ++i;
            count1++;
          }//if
          else {
            cout << i->getTag() << " " << p->getTag() << endl;
            cout << i->getPair() << " " << p->getPair() << endl;
            cout << i->getLife() << " " << p->getLife() << endl;
            p->incrementPair();
            i->incrementPair();
            newPopCount++;
            count1++;
            count++;
            p++;
            i++;            
          }//else     
        }//for
      }//else
    }//for 
    Time += 0.05;
    for ( vector<Element>::iterator m = vec.begin(); m != vec.end(); ++m ) {
      m->incrementLife();
      if ( m->getLife() >= 1.00 ) {
        Dead++; 
        //vec.clear();
        vec.erase(m);
        //vec.shrink_to_fit();
      }//if
      for (int i = 0; i = newPopCount; i++) {
        Element woo;
        woo.setValues(0.0, rand()%2);
        vec.push_back(woo);
      }//for
    }//for 
    cout << "The total number of dead is: " << Dead << endl;
    cout << "The total number born is: " << newPopCount << endl;
    cout << "Current population is: " << vec.size() << endl;
    cout << "Population has survived for: " << Time << endl;
    sleep(1);
  }//while



  cout<< "The populace is now extinct." << endl;
  cout<< "The populace survived for: " << Time << endl;

}//main
```

You can see my silly debugging methods, I was getting a Segmentation Fault error before, but I believe that to be fixed. The issue now is that I'm getting stuck in the loops. The program seems to run almost erratically, and I can't pinpoint the issue any closer than inside of one of the loops.
My Dead integer is incremented and displayed properly, but the newPopCount integer is not, which makes no sense to me.
Also the program never gets out of the while loop, it will continue until it gets stuck in another of the many loops I have.
I have had several other issues, which I've been fixing slowly but surely as you can see by my patchwork code.
Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is C++, not C. Please don't tag it as such.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart removed it.

Comment: `}//for` -- please **no.** Indent that closing brace properly instead.

Comment: Do something for the indentation

Comment: You might try breaking things down into smaller functions to make it easier to debug.

Comment: iterating over an array you are modifying is a cardinal sin. In this case you are changing `vec` while iterating over it. If you were looking at the fourth element and decided to erase it, do you expect to go to the "old" fifth element (now the fourth), or the "new" fifth element (was the sixth).

Comment: The //for was for my benefit earlier in the program, I had so many unnecessary loops before. Making it look pretty will come after I fix the major issues.

Comment: @ScottyMorris identation is not for prettiness, it is for the ease of understanding code in order to fix it more easily !

Comment: Making it look pretty might help you avoid major issues.  If you can't read the code you don't know what it's doing.

Comment: @Floris I thought that iteration only made it easier for me to call upon objects inside of the vector?
Also, the idea was that the removal of the objects would come after the vector had been searched once through for possible pairs.

Comment: @ScottyMorris No - when you delete an element in a vector you are iterating over, you get unexpected behavior. For instance, if you say you are increasing m (0,1,2,3...) then when you delete item 1 and go on to item "2", you skipped the original item 2 (which is the new "item 1" in the vector). Example: start with A,B,C,D. Element 0 = A; Element 1 = B; delete it. Now element 2 = D, and you never looked at C. But that's only one issue...

Comment: @ScottyMorris ***Indentation is not about prettiness, it is about understanding and code quality***. The compiler could grok your program even if it almost fitted on one line, but it would be utterly unreadable for a human being. If you are graduating in something related to computer science, you **definitely must learn how to indent your code in an acceptable fashion**, failing to do so is not an option if you want to become a programmer. This is not just for others reading your code, but for you reading your own code in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two obvious issues, which your compiler will warn you about if you turn up your warnings high enough.

First:

```
void incrementPair() {
    pair = pair++;
}
```

This is undefined behavior. Should be just:

```
void incrementPair() {
    ++pair;
}
```

Second:

```
for (int i = 0; i = newPopCount; i++) {
    Element woo;
    woo.setValues(0.0, rand()%2);
    vec.push_back(woo);
}
```

That condition in your `for` loop is almost certainly wrong. It likely should be `i <= newPopcount`, or something like that.

As a side note, your `setValues()` member function looks like it's doing the job that a constructor should be doing.

EDIT: Look here:

```
for(int count = 0; count != vec.size(); ) {
    std::vector<Element>::iterator p = vec.begin();
    std::vector<Element>::iterator i = vec.begin() + 1;
```

Imagine you have a `std::vector` with only one element in it, and then think about what `i` is going to represent when you do `i->getLife()` a few lines later. Just having those definitions inside the `for` loop looks a bit suspicious in itself, since you increment both `p` and `i` during the loop, but you're going to reset them again on every iteration, but it's not all that easy to follow the logic, so perhaps that's what you intended.

Comment: Ah, these just seem to be oversights on my part. I appreciate your help. I'd +1, but my reputation isn't quite high enough.   Whooooa, after implementing the fixes you mentioned, I get a crazy error message along the lines of an "invalid pointer" but then my console goes on to print a lot of memory addresses.

Comment: This is very helpful, I lost a lot of "programming momentum" at this point, so hopefully this will get me started again.

Comment: If you want some advice, I'd suggest breaking things out into more functions. Even simple boolean checks like `if ((i->getLife() < 0.25) || (i->getLife() > 0.50) || (i->getPair() == 2) || (p->getTag() == i->getTag())`, put them as a function, and give them a meaningful name, will make your logic much easier to follow, and make it easier to write your program.

Comment: For example, in that particular case, something like `if ( is_reproductive_age(*i) || is_paired(*i, *p) ) { /* ...`.

Answer (score 1):

`vec.erase(m);` results in an invalid `m`. You want to do `m = vec.erase(m)`